# quiero borrar un usuario en la base de datos de Oracle pero no me deja

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, cuenta-usuario, eliminar

El error básicamente es este ORA-28014: no se pueden borrar los usuarios administrativos
Me parece que es un error absurdo por que el usuario que cree le di permisos muy específicos de consultas y de iniciar sesión y mas nada, no le di ningún permiso para administrar a ningún otro usuario ni nada como para que me este saliendo este error fastidioso.

También agarre y en el usuario system le quite al usuario a eliminar, que llamé jeff, todos los privilegios y permisos en general pero aun así Oracle esta empeñado en decir que el usuario es administrativo y que no se puede eliminar.

Lo que me enfurece es que cuando lo creé me permitía borrar o hacer lo que me diera la gana con usuarios 100% similares (usé las mismas sentencias de código) pero una vez reiniciado el sistema, le entro la gana de no dejarme borrarlo por ningún motivo.

Estará administrando el vacío por que no puede hacer nada.
Si alguien tiene alguna solución a esto le agradecería bastante.

Comment: fijate si te sirve esto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49729044/73749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar excepcionalmente este parámetro porque puede provocar inconsistencias en los metadatos de la bd como se menciona aquí. https://mikedietrichde.com/2020/02/10/be-aware-when-you-use-_oracle_script-in-scripts/

```
SQL> alter session set “_oracle_script“=true;

Session altered

SQL> drop user usuario_x cascade;

User dropped.
```

Answer (score -1):

Así lo hice yo, un poco más simple y corto.

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = true;
DROP USER miusuario CASCADE;
```

Comment: No es exactamente igual que la otra respuesta?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada, en este caso te sugerimos revisar la respuesta y agregar una que aporte otra solución, ya que esta información es la misma que la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: muy parecida al respuesta anteriores